# Is it possible to use 2x assets on a 3x device in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-android

I have a iOS and Android app, written in Flutter. I have an assets folder with `png` files, structured in standard Flutter fashion with `1.5x`, `2x`, `3x` and `4x` sub-folders.

I have added this to `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  assets:
    - assets/
```

This works fine.

But for a specific set of images I would like to only have them in one size, say `2x` and the just scale those for the other sizes. I am aware that this will make them a bit fuzzy but for those specific images this is ok.

For native iOS development I could just include the `2x` images and iOS would automatically choose those and scale them, e.g. on a 3x device.

Is there a way to achive the same with Flutter?

If I just delete the assets in the 3x folder, I get an exception on a 3x device.

Comment: Do you have a svg image for 2x ?

Comment: The asset in question is not suitable for vector representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to come closer to automatic scaling is according to my tests to include 1x and 2x assets. This seems to lead Flutter to use the 2x assets also for 3x devices.

If I include only 2x assets in the project it will fail with an exception at runtime. If I include only 1x assets, those will be used and scaled. If I include both 1x and 2x assets, the 2x assets will be used and scaled.

Scaled 2x assets looks significantly less fuzzy on a 3x device (iPhone X) and when 1x assets are used.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware) from the official flutter documentation.

Here the following example is provided on how to use numeric identifiers that correspond to the nominal resolution of the images:

```
.../my_icon.png
.../2.0x/my_icon.png
.../3.0x/my_icon.png
```

Comment: I know all about the default way when you have the asset in all the sizes. As I try (perhaps failed) to explain, I specifically want to leave out the 1x, 3x, etc sizes for a specific asset.